# find_by_whatever does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have default rails app with rails 3.1.0 and active support 3.1.0. I tried this here in the rails console.

```
user = User.find_by_email("test@test.de")
```

It returns nil. But these here returns a user:

```
user = User.where("email = ?", "test@test.de")
```

I am not understanding why the "find_by_email" does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @taro I don't think it would work.

Comment: @Robert if you're on 1.9.2 please do `User.method(:find_by_email).source_location` and show us the result of that. Perhaps something else is overriding this method and it's not going to AR? Second thing to try if that's not working is to inspect the SQL that AR is generating for this query and see if it's any different from the version that works.

Comment: User.find_by_email(:email => "test@test.de") returns nil, too.

Comment: Hey Ryan. I tried your code. It returns this here: NameError: undefined method `find_by_email' for class `Class'

Comment: What do you mean with default scope? I know what a scope is, but I don't know what a default scope is. I have one scope in the User class. scope :admin, where(:admin => true)